# Do magic weapon/Implement bonuses affect extra damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, monk, damage, implements

I'm going over my monk character and moving him into the Fight Club iPhone app and one thing I noticed was that the implement damage bonus from my Cascading Strikes Ki Focus was being added to my powers that have and extra damage roll for specific situations.

For example, my Open the Gate of Battle power normally does 2d10 + Dex mod [5] + Magic Ki Focus [1] damage but if the target is at full hit points, the attack deals and additional 1d10 damage (stated in the Hit portion).

Would my Cascading Strikes Ki focus add to that extra damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

Extra damage is part of the original damage instance, just like the Enhancement Bonus from the Ki focus. You do not add your Enhancement bonus to critical dice either.

There are some powers however that do *secondary* damage, like Flame Spiral. They benefit from most feats and items effecting the *primary* damage, and can be recognised by the absence of the "extra" word.